# How to force a file to rename by PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I get the following error when trying to rename a file in Powershell on Windows Server 2022.

> The action can't be completed because the folder or a file in it is open in another program

Is there any solution to be able to force the file to be renamed?

Comment: No, not as long as the file is still open by the other program. If it is a temporary issue, you could attempt to retry the rename operation with some wait in between. But ultimately the other program will have to let go of the file.

Comment: Please show us the code you're using when trying to rename the file

Comment: first you must remove the lock - see: https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-manage-open-file-handles-with-powershell/